# Average time on page is 0 even after adding another event

Tags: gwt, google-analytics

I understand that in Google Analytics, if the user just visits the page for a while and then leaves without doing further interaction, the time registered will be equal to 0.

In order to solve this problem, I added the following (Note: I'm using GWT):

```
Window.addCloseHandler(new CloseHandler<Window>() {

    @Override
    public void onClose(CloseEvent<Window> event) {
        GoogleAnalyticsWrapper.endSession();
    }
});
```

Where the function endSession looks as follows:

```
public static native void endSession() /*-{
    $wnd.ga('send', 'event', 'Session', 'Ending', {'sessionControl': 'end'});
}-*/;
```

So what I did basically was to send another event just as the window closes, that way an interaction is happening and the time should not be zero. I also added a sessionControl end command to make sure that the session ends.

However, I'm still getting a zero, so does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: *"[..]send **another** event[..]"*  - What is your "page view" code look like? Is it the same as your `endSession`, sent as an "event" too (with a different label)? If all you are sending are events then there is no page to track time for.